# Cannot update my app in the ios store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I currently have an app with version 1.0 that just got approved for the ios store.
The approval time was a little more then two weeks and during that time I fixed a major issue on my app. to test this version out on TestFlight with my testers I gave it a version 1.1 . Now I wanted to submit my 1.1 version app to the app store. In order to do that I clicked the add version but on my app and added the version 1.1. Now when I attempt to upload my project using XCODE I get the following error

[image]

Any suggestions on how I can fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already posted the correct 1.1 build to TestFlight then you don't need to upload it again.  You can submit it using iTunes Connect without uploading again.

If you want to submit a revised 1.1 build to the App Store, then you need to change the build number.